# How do I suppress warnings when linking a library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

This isn't about warnings from *headers*; it's about warnings from the actual source files that are getting (statically) linked.

In my particular case, when I'm linking my program:

```
g++ -o program myfile1.o myfile2.o libexternal_library.a
```

GCC is warning me that `tmpnam` is dangerous, and that `mkstemp` would be better:

> libexternal_library.a(libexternal_library_la-Impl.o): In function `ns::createTempFile()':
>   Impl.cpp:(.text+0xdab): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'

While GCC might be right, it's not my code that is using `tmpnam`; it's an external library that I'm just linking to. How can I disable/turn off these warnings caused by linking to an external library like this?

If these were header issues, I'd just use `-isystem`, but these aren't headers...

Comment: A quick google search returns a [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12017) and `-Wno-deprecated-declarations`. Some claim this flag helps, some claim it doesn't.